# Parametize columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pymssql

I would like to parametize the columns and my dataframe in an cursor.execute function. I'm using pymssql, because I like the fact that I can name the parametized columns. Yet I still don't know how to properly tell python that I'm referring to a specific dataframe and I would like to use this columns. Here is the last part of my code (I already tested the connection to my database etc. and it works):

```
with conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""insert into [dbo].[testdb] (day, revenue) values (%(day)s, %(revenue)s)""", dataframe)
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in result:
        print(list(row))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-037e289ce76e> in <module>
     10 with conn:
     11     cursor = conn.cursor()
---> 12     cursor.execute("""insert into [dbo].[testdb] (day, revenue) values (%(day)s, %(revenue)s""", dataframe)
     13     result= cursor.fetchall()
     14 

src\pymssql.pyx in pymssql.Cursor.execute()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1477     def __nonzero__(self):
   1478         raise ValueError(
-> 1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1481         )

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: You should show a (almost) real query and say how you would like to change it. Currently I just see an insert query followed with a fetchall (???) and an apparently unrelated error message.

Comment: I edited the query and inserted the entire error message. I hope that this helps with the understanding of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what my problem was. Due to the fact that I converted my dataframe to a dictionary (used dataframe.to_dict'index') the dictionary was a nested dict. I referred it with `dataframe[0]` and it worked. Just in case someone had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess why you want to use fetchall after an insert query: fetchall is normally used for select queries.

`execute` normally inserts one single row into a table. PEP-249 recommends to use `executemany` if you want to insert many rows at a time. But the problem in that the parameter is expected to be an iterable of *records*: an iterable of iterables if you use positional parameters (`?` or `:1`, ...), or an iterable of mappings if you use named parameters. And a dataframe is not that. But you can convert it to a list of dicts with `.to_dict(orient='record)`. So this should work (it does on my tests using SQLite3):

```
cursor.executemany("""insert into [dbo].[testdb] (day, revenue) values (%(day)s, %(revenue)s)""",
                dataframe.to_dict(orient='record'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I'll try it out. I still had the fetchall statement in, because I tested my connection with an select-statement.

Comment: I tried it out and got this error

src\pymssql.pyx in pymssql.Cursor.execute()

src\_mssql.pyx in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query()

src\_mssql.pyx in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query()

src\_mssql.pyx in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query()

src\_mssql.pyx in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_sql_command()

src\_mssql.pyx in _mssql._substitute_params()

ValueError: 'params' arg (<class 'list'>) can be only a tuple or a dictionary.

Comment: @Fullbringa: just realized that I wrote `execute` when is should be `executemany`

Comment: I'm afraid that this also didn't produced the desired outcome. I still get an error message:
ProgrammingError: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near '('.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

Comment: @Fullbringa: This one I can understand! I blindly copy the SQL text from your question and the final `)` was missing... I have just fixed it in my answer

Comment: I already figured that one out, but it still gives me the same bloody ProgrammingError.

Comment: I do not use MSSQL, so I cannot really help for SQL syntax errors. My only advice would be to first test the query  in an interactive SQL tool...

Comment: The query itself works. It's only the last part where i tell my script to dynamically take choose these columns and the reference of the dataframe where my problem is.